# Is it possible to use a custom naming strategy for auto generated Doctrine DiscriminatorMaps?

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I am working a custom bundle which should be used in different Symfony 5+ projects. The bundle includes some entities which inherit from the same [Mapped Superclass](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.10/reference/inheritance-mapping.html):

```
/**
 * @ORM\InheritanceType("SINGLE_TABLE")
 * @ORM\Table(name="vehicles")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorColumn(name="vehicle_type", type="string")
 * @ORM\DiscriminatorMap({
 *      "race_car" = "RaceCar",
 *      "sailboat" = "Sailboat",
 *      ...})
 */
abstract class Vehicle {
    /** @Column(type="string") */
    protected $color;

    // ... more fields and methods
}

/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class RaceCar extends Vehicle {
    ...
}


/**
 * @ORM\Entity
 */
class SailBoat extends Vehicle {
    ...
}
```

This works fine and it is no problem to use a custom naming strategy (or completely custom type names) in the `DiscriminatorMap`.

Now I would like to add more `Vehicle` sub classes to a project which uses the bundle. Since it seems not to be possible to extend the `DiscriminatorMap` outside its original definition (is it?), I switched to not specifying a map manually but letting Doctrine build it automatically:

> If no discriminator map is provided, then the map is generated
> automatically. The automatically generated discriminator map contains
> the lowercase short name of each class as key.

While this works in a new project, all existing entries in the database of an existing project already use the custom naming. This would conflict with the auto generated lowercase naming: e.g. `race_car` vs. `racecar`.

**Is it possible to provide a custom naming strategy which is than be used by Doctrine to build the map?**

Or do I have to manually update the database by replacing the old mapping names with the new (lowercase) ones?

Comment: i guess u should use automatic generation for all abstractions of `Vehicle` and not a mix. U also would not have to do anything manual, u can use the  `doctrine:schema:update` commands

Comment: Thanks @johnSmith. I know that `doctrine:schema:update` handles new/updated tables, row, types, etc. but I was not aware, that it can also be used to handles such changes. I will give it a try!